# Python script to return list of a systemd units log messages from systemd's journal

Tags: python, logging, system, monitoring

I have a school assignment where i need to write a python script that returns a list of systemd units log messages from systemd's journal. Also, it should be recent messages (last 24h and 30 min). For example i would like to get the log messages for sshd.service.
Grateful for any tips to get me started.

Answer (score 1):

#### `python-systemd`

`systemd` has official [python bindings](https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd) which can usually be installed via your package manager, e.g.

```
$ dnf install python3-systemd
```

for Fedora, or

```
$ apt install python3-systemd
```

for Debian and derivatives. If in a virtualenv, you can install directly from Git repo with `pip`:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/systemd/python-systemd
```

`python-systemd` has a clear and consise API; here is an example script that fetches the journal entries logged for `sshd.service` in last 24 hours, mimicking `journalctl` default format:

```
import datetime
import systemd.journal


if __name__ == '__main__':
    date_last_24h = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    reader = systemd.journal.Reader()
    reader.seek_realtime(date_last_24h.timestamp())
    reader.log_level(systemd.journal.LOG_INFO)
    reader.add_match(_SYSTEMD_UNIT='sshd.service')
    for entry in reader:
        print(
            '{} {} {}: {}'.format(
                entry['__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP'].strftime('%B %d %H:%M:%S'),
                entry['_HOSTNAME'],
                entry['_SELINUX_CONTEXT'],
                entry['MESSAGE'],
            )
    )
```

#### Querying journal with stdlib only (`subprocess`)

If you are not allowed to install `python-systemd`, resort to invoking `journalctl` with appropriate query args:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = subprocess.run(shlex.split('journalctl -u systemd-udevd --since today'))
    raw_output = result.stdout
    print(raw_output)
```

However, you are responsible for splitting the output in lines and parsing out the relevant information of each entry, which can quickly turn out more cumbersome than using the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you could follow:

- Try the to see the logs command manually, A search for 'systemd logs' would lead you to something like: https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-use-journalctl/
- Think how you can run the needed command from python. A search for 'call external command from python' would lead you to https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
- Then see how you can parse the output, convert it into string, then maybe search for keywords, regular expressions. etc.

Comment: Hi, the first link was "not found". :/